# Getting Stratified data from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.  Teams and Players.  What I want to do is create a query that tells me some statistical data about the salary of the largest team.  Specifically I want a count of how many players make less than 5K.  How many make between 5K and 10K ....in increments of 5K to the max player.

Here is the SQL:

```
CREATE  TABLE `formsfiles`.`Teams` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );


INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Sharks');
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Jets');
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Fish');
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Dodgers');


CREATE  TABLE `Players` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Team_ID` INT NULL ,
  `Salary` INT NUll ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`, salary) VALUES ('Jim', '1', '4800');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`, salary) VALUES ('Tom', '1', '12000');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`, salary) VALUES ('Harry', '2', '1230');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`, salary) VALUES ('Dave', '2', '19870');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`, salary) VALUES ('Tim', '3', '1540');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`, salary) VALUES ('Trey', '4','7340');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`, salary) VALUES ('Jay', '4', '4800');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`, salary) VALUES ('Steve', '4','6610');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`, salary) VALUES ('Chris', '4','17754');
```

Given this data:  The Dodgers are the largest team  (ID =4)
We would like an output of:

```
0-5000       1
5000-10000   2
10000-15000  0
15000-20000  1
```

If this code looks familiar it is because it is an evolution of a problem of a prior problem I posted here.  Kindly don't beat me down!

Comment: you can select them with simple between condition and union them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do almost what you want

```
SELECT 5000 * FLOOR(Salary / 5000), count(*)
FROM Players 
WHERE Team_ID = 4
GROUP BY FLOOR(Salary / 5000)
```

It returns the low border of the range and the number of entries

```
0        1
5000     2
15000    1
```

Note that it does not return empty ranges.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my attempt at this.  It uses joins to satisfy the conditions:

```
select sr.range,
       SUM(case when p.salary >= sr.low and p.salary < sr.high then 1 else 0 end)          
from Players p join
     (select t.id
      from Players p join
           Teams t
           on p.team_id = t.id
      group by t.team_id
      order by SUM(p.salary) desc
      limit 1
     ) team
     on p.team_id = team.id cross join
     (select '0-5000' as range, 0 as low, 5000 as high union all
      select '5000-10000', 5000, 10000 union all
      select '10000-15000', 10000, 15000 union all
      select '15000-20000', 15000, 20000
     ) sr
group by sr.range
order by min(sr.low)
```

Notice the use of a separate query for the ranges, to be sure that you get rows with a count of 0.